# Why my SQL query not using the table's index?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-indexes

I have a test table with the columns: id (primary key), name, orderby

**Indexes:**
Primary (id)

index Non-unique (orderby)

**I execute the query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY `orderby` DESC;
```

**In the Explain report, i see:**
[image]

And in my slow_query_log_file so that query does not use the index...why?

**If I change the index to Primary so he does use:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uxnl.png)

**SHOW CREATE TABLE test:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4eYt.png)

Comment: Provide complete output for `SHOW CREATE TABLE test;`. And sync the textual query and the query on the screenshot.

Comment: *And in my slow_query_log_file so that query does not use the index...* The query which selects 2 rows? really? PS. Filesorting for 2 rows is faster than index usage.

Comment: This is just an example table haha ... it's exactly the same problem in other tables

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many rows are returend in your query. But indexes are used to access data by addressing them. when you use "select *" whitout specifieng any column and without where clause, the database need to read the whole table to gather data you want. The performance would be better if you use column name You needed.

Comment: Why when I change the index to 'primary' instead 'index' then it does display as an using index?